# Swift catching error

Tags: swift

Why is

```
            if error = response.result.error else {
                print (error)
            }
```

Not allowed and throws an error within the function below? I would have expected it should go through well.

```
    Alamofire.request(Router.RegisterUser(parameters))
        .validate()
        .responseJSON(completionHandler: { (response) -> Void in

            if let receivedData = response.result.value {
                let json = JSON(receivedData)

                // Check for error in JSON
                if let message = json["error"]["message"].string {
                    let error = Error.errorWithCode(.DataSerializationFailed, failureReason: message)
                    print(error)
                    return
                }
                completionHandler(.Success(true), response: JSON(receivedData))
            }

            if error = response.result.error else {
                print (error)
            }
    })
```

I use the validate function to avoid successful responses to the completionhandler, when indeed an error code is returned by the server. The problem now is, that the only error I can currently receive is the one, thrown by `validate()`. But I use error handling in my API as well and will return a suitable error message to the user.

> Error Domain=com.alamofire.error Code=-6003 "Response status code was
>   unacceptable: 400" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Response status
>   code was unacceptable: 400}

How can I achieve this now? As by using validate, the response will never get processed as far as I understand?

```
    Alamofire.request(Router.RegisterUser(parameters))
        .validate()
        .responseJSON(completionHandler: { (response) -> Void in
            switch(response.result) {
            case .Success(let response):
                print(response)
            case .Failure(let error):
                print("FAILURE: \(error)")
            }
         })
     }
```

Comment: Looks like you're probably missing a `let`.  This question should be closed.  Either it's a simple typographical error and you've omitted the `let` keyword, or it's something else... but you've failed to include the actual error message.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be 2 issues in your code:

1. You are missing a `let` or `guard` to check if there is an error.
2. `print(error)` should be inside if as you are checking error is not `nil`  and trying to print error in else which will be nil.

Comment: Hmm.. you are right. I adjusted the question a bit more, as I am now running into problems with the return values of the validate function of Alamofire. I do not get access to any other info, than the one above. Can I change this behaviour?

Comment: You can check on below link for more usage on Validate: https://m.reddit.com/r/swift/comments/3b7ddx/alamofire_validate_how_to_handle_error/